DataGridViewComboBoxCell with different entries, as selected in another DataGridViewComboBoxCell
I've been struggling with a problem of having two DataGridViewComboBoxCell columns in a datagrid. Upon changing an item in column 1 in given row, I want the corresponding cell in column 2 to change its droplist items. I attached very simple script below for such a dialog, see the attached image.
By default column 2 has no entries. Now when you do the following sequence

In column 1 selectect "1", this triggers col1Changed event and updates cell items in column 2
In column 2, select "item 1".
Try to select something in column 1

This triggers the following exception:
The following exception occurred in the DataGridView:
System.ArgumentException: DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid.
To replace this default dialog please handle the DataError event.
How can I avoid this exception?
Thanks
See my code for this problem below:
void initaliseGrid()
{
    string[] itemsCol1 = new string[] { "1", "2", "3" };
    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn col1 = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    col1.DropDownWidth = 200;
    col1.Width = 200;
    col1.MaxDropDownItems = 3;
    col1.HeaderText = "col 1";
    col1.ReadOnly = false;
    dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, col1);
    col1.Items.AddRange(itemsCol1);

    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn col2 = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    col2.DropDownWidth = 200;
    col2.Width = 200;
    col2.MaxDropDownItems = 3;
    col2.HeaderText = "col 2";
    col2.ReadOnly = true;
    dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(1, col2);

}

int col1Idx = 0;
int col2Idx = 1;

private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    // Check if the curent cell is combobox
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == colqIdx && e.Control is ComboBox)
    {
        ComboBox comboBox = e.Control as ComboBox;
        // Add an event when combobox index is changed
        comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += col1Changed;
    }
}

private void col1Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var currentcell = dataGridView1.CurrentCellAddress;
    if (currentcell.X == col1Idx)
    {
        // Read the selected item
        string selectedItem = ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem.ToString();
        // Get the cellfrom column 2
        DataGridViewComboBoxCell comboBox = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[currentcell.X].Cells[col2Idx];
        if (selectedItem == "1")
        {
            comboBox.Items.Clear();
            comboBox.Items.Add("item1");
            comboBox.Items.Add("item2");
            comboBox.ReadOnly = false;
        }
        else if (selectedItem == "2")
        {
            comboBox.Items.Clear();
            comboBox.Items.Add("item3");
            comboBox.Items.Add("item4");
            comboBox.ReadOnly = false;
        }
        else
        {
            comboBox.Items.Clear();
            comboBox.ReadOnly = true;
        }
    }
}



In dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing there's a variable colqIdx with no number. It should be col1Idx. (The code does not compile)

I also get a null reference exception in string selectedItem = ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem.ToString();. Change it to (string)((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem;. And replace X by Y here .Rows[currentcell.Y].

In the grid's EditingControlShowing event, you must remove the ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged event handler before adding it again. Or assign the editing control (ComboBox) to a class field to remove the handler in the DGV.CellEndEdit event (if it's not null) and set it to null.

Also, and as alternative, implement the CellValueChanged event (which is fired when you change CB selection), if e.ColumnIndex == 0, get the selected Value, cast the col2 cell of the current row to DataGridViewComboBoxCell, and fill/bind its Items / DataSource accordingly.

I was able to easily reproduce your DataError exception and the root cause is that whenever the DataGridView refreshes, it tries to synchronize the displayed value with one of the available items in the combo box. But if you change the available options in the combo box, it can no longer find the displayed value and throws the DataError exception.
As I understand it, You'd like to have different options for different index values, something like this for example:
    enum OptionsOne { Select, Bumble, Twinkle, }
    enum OptionsTwo { Select, Whisker, Quibble, }
    enum OptionsThree { Select, Wobble, Flutter, }



To handle the Refresh issue, you can experiment with using binding to suppress any change to the Option value if the incoming value isn't a currently available option. Here's an example for the bound record class:
class Record : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    static int _recordCount = 1;
    public string Description { get; set; } = $"Record {_recordCount++}";

    // By initially setting index to '1' and Available options
    // to `OptionsOne` every record is born in sync with itself.
    public int Index
    {
        get => _index;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_index, value))
            {
                _index = value;
                switch (Index)
                {
                    case 1: AvailableOptions = Enum.GetNames(typeof(OptionsOne)); break;
                    case 2: AvailableOptions = Enum.GetNames(typeof(OptionsTwo)); break;
                    case 3: AvailableOptions = Enum.GetNames(typeof(OptionsThree)); break;
                }
                if (Option is string currentOption && !AvailableOptions.Contains(currentOption))
                {
                    Option = AvailableOptions[0];
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Option));
                }
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    int _index = 1;

    [Browsable(false)]
    public string[] AvailableOptions { get; set; } = Enum.GetNames(typeof(OptionsOne));
    public string? Option
    {
        get => _option;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_option, value))
            {
                if (Option is string currentOption && AvailableOptions.Contains(value))
                {
                    _option = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    string? _option = $"{OptionsOne.Select}";

    public virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
}



A secondary issue is that you might change the Index value, and now the currently selected value is no longer a valid available choice, so another aspect of this binding is that the record will reset to the safe "common" value of Select if that occurs.


The only thing that remains to be done is making sure the available selections track the selected item. This can be done in a handler for the CurrentCellChanged event as shown in this initialization routine:
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm() => InitializeComponent();
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        int replaceIndex;
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cbCol;

        base.OnLoad(e);
        dataGridView.DataSource = Records; 
        dataGridView.Columns[nameof(Record.Description)].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;

        // Index column
        cbCol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
        {
            Name = nameof(Record.Index),
            DataSource = new int[] {1,2,3},
            DataPropertyName = nameof(Record.Index),
        };
        replaceIndex = dataGridView.Columns[nameof(Record.Index)].Index;
        dataGridView.Columns.RemoveAt(replaceIndex);
        dataGridView.Columns.Insert(replaceIndex, cbCol);

        // Option column
        cbCol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
        {
            Name = nameof(Record.Option),
            DataSource = Enum.GetNames<OptionsOne>(),
            DataPropertyName = nameof(Record.Option),
        };
        replaceIndex = dataGridView.Columns[nameof(Record.Option)].Index;
        dataGridView.Columns.RemoveAt(replaceIndex);
        dataGridView.Columns.Insert(replaceIndex, cbCol);
        dataGridView.CurrentCellChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var cbCol = ((DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dataGridView.Columns[nameof(Record.Option)]);
            if (dataGridView.CurrentCell is DataGridViewComboBoxCell cbCell && cbCell.ColumnIndex == cbCol.Index)
            {
                var record = Records[dataGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex];
                cbCell.DataSource = record.AvailableOptions;
            }
        };
        dataGridView.DataError += (sender, e) =>
        {
            Debug.Fail("We don't expect this to happen anymore!");
        };
        // Consider 'not' allowing the record to be dirty after a CB select.
        dataGridView.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if(dataGridView.CurrentCell is DataGridViewComboBoxCell)
            {
                if (dataGridView.IsCurrentCellDirty)
                {
                    BeginInvoke(()=> dataGridView.EndEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit));
                }
            }
        };
        Records.Add(new Record());
        Records.Add(new Record());
        Records.Add(new Record());
    }
    BindingList<Record> Records { get; } = new BindingList<Record>();
}


One more subtlety. In your original code, changing a CB selection is going to make the record dirty and uncommitted. By handling the CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged event you can go ahead and commit immediately if desired.


Here's the code I used to test this answer. Clone Of course, let me know if you find any issues with it.

This is lovely, exectly what I was asking for, thank you so much! I'm using  C# v 7.3 in my project, so will need to replace some of the hacks you used like nullable reference types, but that's fine.

Thx for the feedback! Let me know if there's any issues porting to 7.3 and I also wanted to let you know about a slightly-slicker way to do this that occurred to me and so I put it in the repo as an alternate branch named bind-when-list-changes vis-à-vis this one which is bind-when-cell-selection-changes.  The question you're asking in your post is a good one IMO ▲.

I'll try to visualize the issue with showing the values for column 2 at each step.

You select value 1 in Cell [0,0]. Second cell [0,1] is set to {item1, item2}
You select {item1} in cell. The list behind is still {item1, item2}
You select value 2 in Cell [0,0]. Second cell [0,1] is set to {item3, item4}. However the value of cell [0,1] is still {item1} which is not a valid selection anymore!

To fix the issue, simply reset the value of the cell in the second column before altering the comboBox items by setting comboBox.Value = null. However I'd suggest you read about data binding. Manually altering data structures is prone to errors.
private void col1Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var currentcell = dataGridView1.CurrentCellAddress;
    if (currentcell.X == col1Idx)
    {
        // Read the selected item
        string selectedItem = ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem.ToString();
        // Get the cellfrom column 2
        DataGridViewComboBoxCell comboBox = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[currentcell.X].Cells[col2Idx];
        comboBox.Value = null;
        if (selectedItem == "1")
        {
            comboBox.Items.Clear();
            comboBox.Items.Add("item1");
            comboBox.Items.Add("item2");
            comboBox.ReadOnly = false;
        }
        else if (selectedItem == "2")
        {
            comboBox.Items.Clear();
            comboBox.Items.Add("item3");
            comboBox.Items.Add("item4");
            comboBox.ReadOnly = false;
        }
        else
        {
            comboBox.Items.Clear();
            comboBox.ReadOnly = true;
        }
    }
}


Thanks, this works indeed. The downside now is that the event col1Changed is trigerred at step 3, as soon as the droplist arrow is selected and the value in column 2 is cleared. This means that if you select something in cell [0, 1], then want to change something in cell [0, 0], your value in cell [0, 1] will be reset (set to null) before you select anything in cell [0, 0]. I thought the issue might be binding, is there other way to achieve the same effect using binding?

Bind to the CellEndEdit event instead. This will only trigger if you finish editing in cell [0,0].

SelectedItem.ToString() throws a NRE. Write (string)((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem instead. Use Y instead of X for the Rows index: Rows[currentcell.Y]. Also the Clear(); is common to all 3 cases. Move it to before the if.

How can you bind to CellEndEdit if the event cannot be cast to ComboBox ComboBox comboBox = e.Control as ComboBox;? Sorry, there should have been Y instead of X.

The event CellEndEdit is not immediatetly trigerred when I change the selected index in cell [0, 0]

My dirty solution to the problem is shown below for col1Changed. Essentially, I'm storing the currect cell value in a temporary variable and if possible, this value should be restored. I'm not 100% happy with this, but it's the best I could come up with.
private void col1Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var currentcell = dataGridView1.CurrentCellAddress;
    if (currentcell.X == col1Idx)
    {
        // Read the selected item
        string selectedItem = (string)((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem;
        // Get the cellfrom column 2
        DataGridViewComboBoxCell comboBox = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[currentcell.Y].Cells[col2Idx];
        // Store the current value in the cell
        string tempValue = (string)dataGridView1.Rows[currentcell.Y].Cells[col2Idx].Value;
        comboBox.Value = null;
        comboBox.Items.Clear();
        if (selectedItem == "1")
        {
            comboBox.Items.Add("item1");
            comboBox.Items.Add("item2");
            comboBox.ReadOnly = false;
        }
        else if (selectedItem == "2")
        {
            comboBox.Items.Add("item3");
            comboBox.Items.Add("item4");
            comboBox.ReadOnly = false;
        }
        else
        {
            comboBox.ReadOnly = true;
        }
        if (tempValue != null && comboBox.Items.Contains(tempValue))
        {
            // Restore the current value in the cell
            comboBox.Value = tempValue;
        }
        else if (comboBox.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            // Set the cell value to the first item from the list
            comboBox.Value = (string)comboBox.Items[0];
        }
    }
}

EDIT:
An even neater solution is to use check if the combobox value has changed using this: if (selectedItem == (string)dataGridView1.Rows[currentcell.Y].Cells[col1Idx].Value)
private void col1Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var currentcell = dataGridView1.CurrentCellAddress;
    if (currentcell.X == col1Idx)
    {
        // Read the selected item
        string selectedItem = (string)((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem;
        // Get the cell from column 2
        DataGridViewComboBoxCell comboBox = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[currentcell.Y].Cells[col2Idx];
        // Check if the combobox value has changed
        if (selectedItem == (string)dataGridView1.Rows[currentcell.Y].Cells[col1Idx].Value)
            return;
        comboBox.Value = null;
        comboBox.Items.Clear();
        if (selectedItem == "1")
        {
            comboBox.Items.Add("item1");
            comboBox.Items.Add("item2");
            comboBox.ReadOnly = false;
        }
        else if (selectedItem == "2")
        {
            comboBox.Items.Add("item3");
            comboBox.Items.Add("item4");
            comboBox.ReadOnly = false;
        }
        else
        {
            comboBox.ReadOnly = true;
        }
        if (comboBox.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            // Set the cell value to the first item from the list
            comboBox.Value = (string)comboBox.Items[0];
        }
    }
}

